# react-native flatlist - keyExtractor returns duplicate item and skips to end of data array

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Reporting strange behaviour here, hope someone has come across this. I get an error "Invariant Violation: A VirtualizedList contains a cell which itself contains more than one VirtualizedList of the same orientation as the parent list. You must pass a unique listKey prop to each sibling list."

Using react native 0.55.4

```
return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
                    console.log(`${item}-${index}`)
                    return `${item}-${index}`;
                }}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={HairSpacer}
            />
        </View>
    );
```

data:

```
["korbit", "kraken", "bitstamp", "bitflyer", "bittrex", "bitfinex", "poloniex", "huobi", "zaif", "coincheck", "bithumb", "coinnest", "btcbox", "okcoin", "aex", "binance", "coinbase", "coinrail", "upbit", "coinone", "kucoin", "gate", "zb", "coin", "gopax"]
```

console:

```
kraken-1 
bitstamp-2 
bitflyer-3 
bittrex-4 
bitfinex-5 
poloniex-6 
huobi-7 
zaif-8 
coincheck-9 
coincheck-9 
gopax-24
```

I'm assuming the error is thrown because of this duplicate list item, although from the data prop you can see that it is not actually a duplicate.

Any advice welcome

Comment: i ran the above code that you mentioned, but i didnot face any issue that you mention. can you provide other details the component class that you had made.

Comment: Hey Prince, thanks for your response. It's simply too much code to upload because it's calling data from a mobx store and it's a Flatlist that is nested in the footer component of another Flatlist. The strange thing is that this component is called elsewhere in exactly the same manner and it works. Upon further investigation it seems that in the buggy case the getNestedChildState function within React-Native VirtualizedList.js is called even though it isn't in the other.

Comment: ok, i got same question, may be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276526/nested-flat-list-invariant-violation-a-virtualizedlist-contains-a-cell-which-it?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

Try using `listkey` instead of `keyExtractor`